# Axios-запрос не работает(CORS)(REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, cors

Пишу на react приложение "курс валют"

Вот метод получения курса

```
    axios.get('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=17.08.2022',{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.exchangeRate;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Значение базовой валюты и валюты сделки передаю в таблицу

```
 return (
       <table className="table-container">
           <tbody>
                <tr>
                     <td>{getQueryPB().baseCurrency}</td>
                 </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td>{getQueryPB().currency}</td>
                 </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
    )
```

но в конечном итоге получаю ошибки:

1)**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=17.08.2022' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

2)**GET https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=17.08.2022 net::ERR_FAILED 200**

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, судя по ошибке, сама она исходит от сайта, тоесть именно там не указаны разрешённые домены.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю что вы указали неправильно второй аргумент. Вторым аргументом должен идти словарь с настройками, а не просто несколько словарей с значениями настроек, которые непонятно куда применять. Попробуйте указать ключ 'header' вот так:

```
axios.get('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=17.08.2022',
  {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
    }
  }
);
```