# Проблема с получением json строки из моего api

Tags: javascript, json

Я новичок! Пытаюсь получить json строку из моего api с аутентификацией windows. Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let amount = $('#amount');
    let created = $('#created');

    $.ajax({
        type:  'Get',
        url: 'https://localhost:44327/api/trade',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (data) {
            amount.append(data.Amount);
            created.append(data.Created);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

Постоянно выкидывает ошибку из блока error. Json ответ выглядит следующим образом.

```
{
"Amount":131670981686210700491833.78,
"Created":"2022-08-17T00:00:00"
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста! [image: Ошибка]

Comment: Что за ошибка у вас? Поделитесь ее текстом

Comment: @SwaD добавил текст

Comment: Ваш сайт блокирует вам выполнение запросов. Суд по ошибке ругается на заголовок. Аналогичный вопрос был [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453846/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453846/axios-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82corsreact)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так попробуй

```
async function getData()
{
    let ctrl = 'https://localhost:44327/api/trade';
    if ($('body')[0] != undefined) {
        var ftch = await fetch(ctrl, {
            method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
            credentials: 'include', // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'//, // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
                // body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response.ok)
                return response.text(); //response.json()
            else
                throw new Error('Fetch error.');
        })
        .then((responseText) => {
            $('body')[0].append(responseText);
            console.log('%j', responseText)
            console.log('fetch response key count: ' + Object.keys(responseText).length)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
}
```

Если не сработает, то надо запускать прокси процесс node js и обращаться по тому же url, с которого ты пытаешься сделать get запрос (сделать прокси-редирект с localhost:44327 на localhost:44362). В ангуляре, например, это файл *proxy.conf.js* https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server.